psycopg2.OperationalError in Airflow
Just started working with apache Airflow, wrote a simple dag. Process fails with that:
File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/init.py", line 122, in connect
conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError
Working on Windows, Airflows runs on WSL, pgAdmin as a DB management tool.
Looks like the problem is the connection to postgres server in this part of the code:
conn = psycopg2.connect(
dbname="random_data",
user="postgres",
password="password",
host="172.25.16.1",
port="5432")
But I checked password, host, posrt, etc. They are definitely correct.
